# AddGeometryColumn returns error 'column does not exist'

Tags: postgis

I'm running PostGIS 3.3.2, and trying to create a new spatial table. I've created a table `dialectpoints`, which currently has nothing but an ID column, and am now trying to add geometry info to it before proceeding to other data columns. As I understand it, this code should be correct:

```
select AddGeometryColumn("dialectpoints","geom",4326,"POINT",2);
```

However, running this query results in the following error:

```
SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column "dialectpoints" does not exist
  Position: 26
```

Of course that column doesn't exist; it's a table, not a column! AddGeometryColumn seems very confused, and I'm not sure why. I know I'm in the right database; `select * from dialectpoints` correctly returns an empty ID column.

This is a new install of PostgreSQL and PostGIS, and I'm rather new at this; I suppose there's a chance I've installed it incorrectly or incompletely somehow. I can run `select postgis_full_version()` and it returns sensible info, so PostGIS is at least active for this database. (The full result is `POSTGIS="3.3.2 POSTGIS_REVISION" [EXTENSION] (liblwgeom version mismatch: "3.3.2 4975da8") PGSQL="150" GEOS="3.11.2-CAPI-1.17.2" PROJ="9.2.0" LIBXML="2.10.4" LIBJSON="0.16" LIBPROTOBUF="1.4.1" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)" (core procs from "3.3.2 4975da8" need`.)

What could be going on here?

Comment: Read the document https://postgis.net/docs/AddGeometryColumn.html and follow the syntax. Strings in ANSI SQL language are within single quotes and  identifiers like column names are within double quotes. PostgeSQL follows the standard, some other databases not exactly.

Comment: You've mixed up your table and column names

Comment: @user30184 Yep, that was the problem. Not used to single and double quotes being so strongly differentiated. Put that in an answer and I'll accept it (^^)